# Test NG Multilevel inheritance

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I am trying to execute the (testng.xml) file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite 1"  verbose="1" >

 <listeners>

   <listener class-name="lib.ListnerImpl" />
 </listeners>

  <test name="Test Validation"> 

    <classes>

    <class name="TestNGAnnotation.Class1"/>
    <class name="TestNGAnnotation.Class2"/>
    <class name="TestNGAnnotation.Class3"/>
    </classes>
    </test>
  </suite>

  Class 1------------------->Has got 2 Test Case
  Class 2 extends Class1------------------>Has got 1 Test Case
  Class 3 extends Class 2------------------>Has got 1 Test Case
```

When i am trying to run this class as independently i am getting the correct result. But when i am trying to execute this through `TestNG.Xml` i am getting the below result in the eclipse Console where it is showing total no of test case as 9. Total execution for Class A as 2 For Class B as 3 and For Class C as 4 wherein i am expecting only 4 Test Case.

[image]

Comment: Which 4 test cases, Which one you don't want ?

Answer (score 0):

Test case which you have defined with `@Test` `annotation` will consider as Separate Test case,